# How to sum the values of column on duplicate key?

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, on-duplicate-key

I have a table like this:

```
// mytable
+----+--------+-------+-------+
| id |  name  |  key  | value |
+----+--------+-------+-------+
| 1  | jack   | 1     | 10    |
| 2  | peter  | 1     | 5     |
| 3  | jack   | 2     | 5     |
| 4  | ali    | 1     | 2     |
| 5  | jack   | 1     | 5     |
| 6  | jack   | 1     | 10    |
| 7  | bert   | 4     | 2     |
| 8  | peter  | 2     | 10    |
| 9  | bert   | 4     | 5     |
+----+--------+-------+-------+
```

Now I want to sum the numbers of `value` where both `name` and `key` are identical. So, I want this output:

```
// mynewtable
+----+--------+-------+-------+
| id |  name  |  key  | value |
+----+--------+-------+-------+
| 1  | jack   | 1     | 25    |
| 2  | peter  | 1     | 5     |
| 3  | jack   | 2     | 5     |
| 4  | ali    | 1     | 2     |
| 7  | bert   | 4     | 7     |
| 8  | peter  | 2     | 10    |
+----+--------+-------+-------+
```

Is it possible to I do that?

---

**Edit:** How can I do that for `insert`?

```
// mytable
+----+--------+-------+-------+
| id |  name  |  key  | value |
+----+--------+-------+-------+
| 1  | jack   | 1     | 25    |
| 2  | peter  | 1     | 5     |
| 3  | jack   | 2     | 5     |
| 4  | ali    | 1     | 2     |
| 7  | bert   | 4     | 7     |
| 8  | peter  | 2     | 10    |
+----+--------+-------+-------+
```

Inserting these rows:

```
    +----+--------+-------+-------+ 
    | 10 | jack   | 1     | 5     |
    +----+--------+-------+-------+ 
    +----+--------+-------+-------+ 
    | 11 | bert   | 1     | 2     |
    +----+--------+-------+-------+
```

What I want: (**output**)

```
// mynewtable
+----+--------+-------+-------+
| id |  name  |  key  | value |
+----+--------+-------+-------+
| 1  | jack   | 1     | 30    |
| 2  | peter  | 1     | 5     |
| 3  | jack   | 2     | 5     |
| 4  | ali    | 1     | 2     |
| 7  | bert   | 4     | 7     |
| 8  | peter  | 2     | 10    |
| 11 | bert   | 1     | 2     |
+----+--------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by `name, key`

```
 select name, key, sum(value) as value 
 from mytable group by name,key
```

Comment: Thanks, +1. Can you please tell me how can I do that for inserting? I want to create a new row if there isn't identical rows *(according to `name` and `key`)*, Also if there is an identical row, then update it and sum their `value` numbers.

Comment: sorry can you explain more i not understand @Shafizadeh

Comment: insert these record on **mytable** @Shafizadeh

Comment: **insert into mytable (name,key,value) VALUES 
    ('jack','1','5'),('bert','1','2')** try this query @Shafizadeh

Comment: This query ^ just inserts ...! I want if both `name` and `key` were equal, `value` get sum.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96354/discussion-between-rahautos-and-shafizadeh).

Answer (score 3):

You have to group by more columns.

```
select name, key, sum(value) from mytable group by name, key;
```

Comment: Thanks. No actually I don't need to new ID, but I like to know how can I do that ... please add to your answer. thanks again. +1

Comment: Sorry, I did not find any easy solution and I don't have much time to find it now

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
CREATE TABLE #testing_123
    ([id] int, [name] varchar(5), [key] int, [value] int)
;

INSERT INTO #testing_123
    ([id], [name], [key], [value])
VALUES
    (1, 'jack', 1, 10),
    (2, 'peter', 1, 5),
    (3, 'jack', 2, 5),
    (4, 'ali', 1, 2),
    (5, 'jack', 1, 5),
    (6, 'jack', 1, 10),
    (7, 'bert', 4, 2),
    (8, 'peter', 2, 10),
    (9, 'bert', 4, 5)
;
```

query used was

```
select min(id) id ,name,[key],sum(value) value from #testing_123 group by name,[key] order by 1
```

output after insert

[image]

Comment: Well, your query is much complicated ..! Actually I can't understand it ..! Also as you see, I can do that using just one `group by` statement simply. anyway thanks for writing an answer under my question.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part (to get the **id** column in the way requested), you could work along:

```
INSERT INTO mynewtable
    (id, name, `key`, `value`)
SELECT
  MIN(id), name, `key`, SUM(`value`)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY name, `key`
;
```

Now, provided **mynewtable** is defined with a unique index on **name** and **key** like

```
CREATE TABLE mynewtable
(id INT, name VARCHAR(5), `key` INT, `value` INT, UNIQUE (name, `key`));
```

you'd get the requested result with

```
INSERT INTO mynewtable
    (id, name, `key`, `value`)
VALUES
    (10, 'jack', 1, 5),
    (11, 'bert', 1, 2)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value` = `value` + VALUES(`value`)
;
```

Beware:

- It requires the unique index on **name** and **key** to work.
- It might not work correctly, if there are other unique indexes and/or a primary key on the same table as well.

**NB**:
Please try to avoid the use of reserved words such as **value** and **key** for, e.g., column names.